# Compare data between 2 rows of same table

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, join

I have a table that looks like this:

```
date1                   date2   
2017-03-06 17:02:00     null  
2017-03-06 17:02:00     2017-02-17 11:20:00  
2017-03-01 17:07:00     2017-03-13 17:07:00  
2017-03-17 12:05:00     null  
2017-01-24 11:45:00     null
```

Which join should I use to output 1 column of data that only shows the `date1` in the result and if there is a value in `date2` column, it will show the `date2` value instead of the `date1` value?

Comment: If you only have one table (and don't want to compare different rows) you don't need a join.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your requirement if both columns are in the same table we could use **ISNULL** to achieve this output?

e.g.

```
select ISNULL(date2, date1) as CalcDate
from <table>
```

Results:

```
CalcDate
2017-03-06 17:02:00.000
2017-02-17 11:20:00.000
2017-03-13 17:07:00.000
2017-03-17 12:05:00.000
2017-01-24 11:45:00.000
```